# Threshold VAR changing the x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I estimated a TVAR model with the package **tsDyn** using the following code:

```
TBVAR <-TVAR(vector, lag=1, nthresh=3, thDelay=2, trim=0.1, mTh=1, plot=TRUE).
```

Now I'd like to change the x-axis of the displayed plot. More precisely, the time span should be displayed on the x-axis (1980-2000). When I estimate the model as described above I got a random values on the x-axis. I've already tried to create a time series `(as.zoo(ts(vector))` and estimate the model again, but that did not work.
I'd appreciate your help:-)

Comment: what does your vector look like?

Comment: actually it is a T* 2 matrix

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?